# Up/Down key not scrolling through unordered list using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This all works great except that users are supposed to be able to scroll up and down the results list using their up/down arrows.  I can't figure out why the up/down just doesn't work at all.  The console is logging that the respective functions are working, but the selection actually does not work.  Any clues would be great.

```
<input id="search_box" type="text" style="float:right;margin-bottom:2px;">

            <div class="suggestions">

                <ul id="results_list">

                </ul>

            </div>

<style>

#results_list {
    width: 220px;
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
}

#results_list li {
    background: white;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
    border-left: solid 1px #eee;
    border-right: solid 1px #eee;
    padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#results_list a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.selected {
    background: black;
}

</style>

<script>

$('#search_box').keyup(function(e) {
    if ($('#search_box').val().length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/jsonrpc',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                jsonrpc: '2.0',
                method: 'search_titles',
                params: [$('#search_box').val()],
                id: 'jsonrpc'
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#results_list').show();
                var items = [];
                $('#results_list').empty();
                $.each(data.result, function(i, item) {
                    items.push("<li><a href='/title/" + item._id + "'>" + item.Name + "</a></li>");
                });
                $('#results_list').append( items.join('') );
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('There was a problem.  Please try again.')
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#results_list').hide();
    }
})

var $listItems = $('li');

$('input').keydown(function(e)
{
    var key = e.keyCode,
        $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
        $current;

    if ( key != 40 && key != 38 ) return;

    $listItems.removeClass('selected');

    if ( key == 40 ) // Down key
    {
        console.log('called down')
        if ( ! $selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child') ) {
            $current = $listItems.eq(0);
        }
        else {
            $current = $selected.next();
        }
    }
    else if ( key == 38 ) // Up key
    {
        console.log('called up')
        if ( ! $selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child') ) {
            $current = $listItems.last();
        }
        else {
            $current = $selected.prev();
        }
    }

    $current.addClass('selected');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
$listItems = $('li')
```

...to the end of your Ajax success callback.

jQuery objects don't automatically refresh themselves to include newly added elements that happen to match their original selector, so your existing code is trying to scroll through a jQuery object (`$listItems`) that doesn't actually contain any elements because it was created before the list was populated.